# Polynomial raised to a polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I came across this question -

$(x^2 - 7x + 11)^{(x^2-13x+42)} = 1$

and I was wondering how many roots will this have? I have a feeling it is trivial, but I am unable to figure this out.

Edit: I know how to find the roots. I found six of them. My question is - how many roots does it have? Not what the roots are.

Comment: **Hint:** $a^b = 1$ can only hold if $a = \pm 1$ or $b = 0$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have made the question a little more clear. I already found six roots of the expression. There is one more case: a=-1 and b is even. But I want to know if there are more roots or just in general know how many roots there are.

Comment: That's a good point; there might be even more roots if $x$ is allowed to be a complex number

Comment: I don't think that there's any quick way to look at an equation like this and know how many roots there are, if that's what you're asking

Comment: By the way, the information about what you have already done would be good context to have included with your question in the first place. Note that in general, users are expected to provide context for their questions, as [is explained in detail here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @David the equations $a = 1, a = -1, b = 0$ could, at least a priori, account for two roots each.

Comment: In the complex plane there are a lot more ways to have $a^b = 1$.

Comment: Your question is *often* presented to students with **no knowledge** of Complex Analysis.  In that setting, limiting the analysis to Real Analysis is customary.  Assuming such a setting, the very first comment following your question, by Ben Grossman pertains.  There is the minor detail that when $a = -1$, $b$ must not be an odd integer.

Comment: Related: [Solving the equation $(x^2-7x+11)^{(x^2-13x+42)} = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3981214)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we're using complex numbers, let me use $z$ for the variable instead of $x$, so $x$ and $y$ can be the real and imaginary parts of $z$.
In the complex plane $a^b$ is multivalued, so we have to decide which branch is to be
used. I'll assume it's the principal branch: $a^b = \exp(b \log(a))$ where $\log(a)$ is the branch of the complex logarithm with imaginary part in $[-\pi, \pi]$.  This will have a branch cut where $a$ is on the negative real axis: with $a = z^2 - 7 z + 11 = (z - 7/2)^2 - 5/4$ that consists of the vertical line $x=7/2$ and the horizontal line segment from  $(7-\sqrt{5})/2$ to $(7+\sqrt{5})/2$.

Plotting with Maple, it appears there will be infinitely many solutions.  Here is a plot
of the curves where the real part of $(z^2-7z+11)^{z^2-13 z + 42}$ is $1$ (in blue)
and the imaginary part is $0$ (in green) in a rectangle in the complex plane.  Each intersection of a blue and a green curve represents a solution.
[image]

Comment: "where $\log(a)$ is the branch of the complex logarithm with imaginary part in $[−\pi,\pi]$" : Minor quibble - I would have presumed that the interval is *half-open*, such as $(-\pi, \pi]$.

Answer (score 0):

You can't tell how many roots there are without computing them. Because if the polynomials have a common root, you will get a case $0^0$ (which you might consider a solution or not), and because a solution of $x^2 - 7x + 11=-1$ needs to pair with an "even" rational exponent (unless you decide that powers of negatives are not allowed).

Nor can we answer precisely for you as we don't know which conventions you use for these special cases. Anyway, there can only be solutions when the first polynomial reaches $\pm1$ or when the second reaches $0$, hence a *maximum* of $6$ roots.